# Docker push command fails to find actual path to my docker file

Tags: docker, github-actions

I am using the docker and github-action tags, as these seem to be the most correct.  I'm new to this, let me know if I can be doing better.

For the course I'm on and the presentation I'll be doing, I'm using github-actions to push a container to Azure and will later do a deploy step using the AcrPull.

For these actions to work, the path that I've set up must be correctly found by the actions.

I'm getting the path error:

```
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/runner/work/DockerDeployDemoVS22EntRepo/**DockerDeployDemoVS22EntRepo**/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Have not heard anything back from the Google Git Group on this, I believe I'm not being taken seriously.

The bold part of the path cannot include the word 'Repo', the path must be ...

```
/home/runner/work/DockerDeployDemoVS22EntRepo/DockerDeployDemoVS22Ent/Dockerfile
```

... in order for the path I have created to work. This is in fact the reason why the docker file can't be found.

Or, is the error mine? Must I not name the 'Repo' part of the path DockerDeployDemoVS22EntRepo? And not name the code part of the path DockerDeployDemoVS22Ent?

Do I have to have the path as

```
/home/runner/work/DockerDeployDemoVS22EntRepo/DockerDeployDemoVS22EntRepo/Dockerfile or /home/runner/work/DockerDeployDemoVS22Ent/DockerDeployDemoVS22Ent/Dockerfile
```

in order for the docker container push (and later pull and deploy) to work?

No one is answering this question. It would appear the path generation to get the segments for /home/runner/work/ to run do not get the actual path but assume that DockerDeployDemoVS22EntRepo/DockerDeployDemoVS22EntRepo/Dockerfile or DockerDeployDemoVS22Ent/DockerDeployDemoVS22Ent/Dockerfile will be the later path elements.

Am I incorrect here? Easily fixed if this is the case but I don't see why the path construction doesn't get the actual path.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a huch: do you have a checkout-action that actually checks out the repository?

Comment: Yep:
        steps:
        # checkout the repo
        - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
          uses: actions/checkout@master

On a hunch, let me rename master to main ...

Nope ... didn't work.

Comment: Can you link the repository?

Comment: Here is the link:  https://github.com/PostalMike/DockerDeployDemoVS22EntRepo/tree/master/DockerDeployDemoVS22Ent

The link does work.

Comment: Okay. From this, the problem is obvious. By default, `docker build ...` looks for a file called `Dockerfile`, and in the working directory of the pipeline job (the root of the project), there is no `Dockerfile`. Which of the dockerfiles should be used to build the image?

Comment: And what is the context directory that should be used to build the image?

Comment: Just added the screen shot showing the Dockerfile lives in .../DockerDeployDemoVS22EntRepo/DockerDeployDemoVS22Ent

... what am I not getting?

Don't know how to snag the 'context directory' -- I'm following along using the instructor's YAML.  All his other YAML works fine and he gets there in the course presentation.

Comment: From the looks of it, the intended context directory is the root of the project. So the docker command to build the image should be `docker build --file DockerDeployDemoVS22Ent/Dockerfile --tag ${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }} .`

Comment: Worky!!!  Thanks.

I'm now getting an auth issue but that's likely due to several attempts at this and having too many secrets for username/password created.  prob just need to scrap all of them and make new secrets all over.  That should fix it.

Will get with the instructor and see if something doesn't need updating in the course.

Please make an answer on this question and I'll upvote it.

Comment: I don't think an answer is necessary. It was just a basic docker question that is explained in [the corresponding documentation (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#file).

Answer (score 0):

The path to the Dockerfile in the Github action is typically relative to the root directory of your Github repository. In your error message, it appears that you're providing an absolute path, which could be causing some issues.

From your question, I am assuming that your repository structure looks something like this:

```
DockerDeployDemoVS22EntRepo
  |__ DockerDeployDemoVS22Ent
        |__ Dockerfile
```

In this case, if you are defining your Github action and need to specify the path to the Dockerfile, it would be `DockerDeployDemoVS22Ent/Dockerfile`. That's the relative path from the root directory of the repository.

So in the Github action step where you build your Docker image, it would look something like this:

```yaml
- name: Build and push Docker images
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
  with:
    context: .
    file: DockerDeployDemoVS22Ent/Dockerfile
    push: true
    tags: user/image-name:tag
```

This should correctly point to your Dockerfile and resolve the path error.

If the Dockerfile is located directly in the root of your repository, then you would simply use `Dockerfile` as the path.

Please try this and let me know if it works for you. If you continue to have issues, providing more information about the structure of your Github repository and the Github action you're using could be helpful for further troubleshooting.